# Future Date minus Now = Days perl

Tags: perl, datetime

Novice here. Sorry and Thanks in advance.
I have a future date

```
(ie:2013-06-09 / $fields[12])
```

I need to subtract today

```
(ie:2013-03-08)
```

to get the number of days remaining.

Comment: Hmm... well, have you already tried searching for similar questions here on stackoverflow? :)  (maybe something like this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821423/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-perl?rq=1)

Comment: Yes I searched and found nothing similar. Your link would've helped. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime). If you start with the date as a string, you could use [DateTime::Format::Strptime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aStrptime) to parse it.

```
use DateTime                   qw( );
use DateTime::Format::Strptime qw( );

my $format = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern   => '%Y-%m-%d',
    time_zone => 'local',
    on_error  => 'croak',
);

my $ref  = DateTime->today( time_zone => 'local' );
my $dt   = $format->parse_datetime('2013-06-09');
my $days = $ref->delta_days($dt)->in_units('days');

print(
   $dt < $ref ? "$days days ago\n" :
   $dt > $ref ? "$days days from now\n" :
   "today\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

use the [DateTime module](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime):

```
use DateTime;

my $d1 = DateTime->new(
      year       => 2013,
      month      => 9,
      day        => 6
);

my $d2 = DateTime->now;
my $diff = $d2->delta_days($d1);

print $diff->delta_days, "\n";  # 182 (from 8/3/2013)
```

Comment: If you don't specify a time zone, it might give an answer that's wrong for where you are. It's not the same date everywhere in the world.

Comment: `$dur->delta_days` is documented as being primarily for internal use. `->in_units('days')` is the preferred interface.

Comment: $dur->delta_days is a math method, and I didn't see your advice in the documentation

Comment: I read the DateTime 0.78 documentation, and delta_days is a math method, according the author's definition

Comment: Then you read the wrong file of DateTime's documentation. You should have been looking at the docs for DateTime::Duration, since that's the method being discussed. It performs no math, and the entirety of its documentation can be summed up to "for internal use". (I had deleted this comment so Miguel could delete his, but his remains and is getting upvotes, so I'll address it again.)