# How to calculate date difference in perl

Tags: perl, date, datetime

I am a novice in perl scripting. I have a requirement where in I need to find the difference of two dates in the minutes/seconds

```
$date1 =  Fri Aug 30 10:53:38 2013
$date2 =  Fri Aug 30 02:12:25 2013
```

can you tell me how do we achieve this, Parsing , calculation , modules req and all

Thanks
Goutham

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I calculate the number of days between two dates in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821423/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-perl)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece) has been a standard part of Perl since 2007.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use Time::Piece;

my $date1 = 'Fri Aug 30 10:53:38 2013';
my $date2 = 'Fri Aug 30 02:12:25 2013';

my $format = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y';

my $diff = Time::Piece->strptime($date1, $format)
         - Time::Piece->strptime($date2, $format);

say $diff;
```

Comment: `Time::Piece->strptime` is for dealing with UTC times. If dealing with local times, use `Time::Piece::localtime->strptime` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Convert both dates to UNIX time

See http://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Parse

Then you can do a simple mathematical subtraction to find the number of seconds between the two.

Then it is simple maths all the way to get minutes, hours, etc.

Comment: Doing math will **not** get you the correct answer.