# To get time difference using perl script

Tags: perl

I want to get the difference between time in minutes. Both the timings to be compared are in same timezone so no worries about the time zone difference and all.

Say if Start_time = 14 Apr 2016 05:02:26
and for end time I need the script to get the current time,

I want to calculate end time -start time.
To get the current time I tried localtime(time),  but I need the current time to be in format of Start time, or if not possible then we can convert start time into the format in which we are getting current time so we can get the difference easily.

Below is what I tried:

```
    #get last line of log
    open my $fh ,"<","$slogfile";
    my $last_line;
    $last_line = $_,while (<$fh>);      
    print OUTLOG "last line of log: $last_line \n";


    if ($last_line=~ m/^(\d\d) (\w{3}) (\d{4}) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d) --/)
        {
    $var = "$1 $2 $3 $4:$5:$6";
    print OUTLOG "$var\n";
        }
    else {
    print OUTLOG "pattern matching didnt work\n";
    }

    #get current time
    my $t = localtime;
    #$t->datetime;
    my $current_time = $t ;
    print OUTLOG "Time is $current_time \n";

    my $cformat = '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y';

    my $diff = Time::Piece->strptime($current_time, $cformat) 
    - Time::Piece->strptime($var, $cformat);
    print OUTLOG "difference is  $diff \n";
```

But I am getting "Error parsing time at C:/Perl/lib/Time/Piece.pm line 469,  line 1071752." error. Please suggest.

Comment: This question isnt a duplicate, here  1> I need to get the current time, in that there are already two times specified. 2> I need to convert either of the time into other to get them both in same format, there  both the timings are already in same format. Please remove the duplicate

Comment: It's close enough to being a duplicate, to justify closing your question. If you read the documentation to the [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module that I use in the answer to the linked question, then that will answer all of your questions. If you have any further questions then please feel free to ask new questions here.

Comment: You've been asking about this same problem for days. The solution is still to use [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece). Read the documentation, and that of [Time::Seconds](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Seconds) and use it in your code. When you have a *specific* problem then post your code in a new question and explain why you can't progress further

Comment: @DaveCross I tried your code of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18525671/how-to-calculate-date-difference-in-perl and got "Error parsing time at C:/Perl/lib/Time/Piece.pm line 469, <$fh> line 1071752." error. Below is what I tried:

Comment: @DaveCross I have added the code tried in question.

Comment: You should really post your new example code as a new question and explain what problems you are having with it. But briefly, to get a time difference, you need two different times. In two different Time::Piece objects. One you get using `localtime()` and the other you get using `Time::Piece->strptime()`. That's not what you're doing here. Here, you're trying to parse `$current_time` which is already a Time::Piece object. That makes no sense.

Comment: @DaveCross I dont wanna get the other time with Time::Peice->strptime(). I just wanna get difference of two variables $current_time & $var in minutes. But the problem is these both are in different formats. Please suggest.

Comment: You have all the information you need. I'm not sure how I can make it any clearer. Post a new question with your current code and explain the problems you are having.

Comment: If you subtract one Time::Piece object from another, you get the time difference in seconds. So you need to get both of the times you're interested in as Time::Piece objects. The current time is easy. That's just `my $t = localtime`. To convert `$var` into a Time::Piece object, you need to use `Time::Piece->strptime()`.

Comment: @DaveCross Explained clearly in a new post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36661965/to-subtract-two-timepeice-objects Kindly look and suggest.