# To subtract two Time:Piece objects

Tags: perl

I want to get the difference between time in minutes. Both the timings to be compared are in same timezone so no worries about the time zone difference and all.

Say if `Start_time = 14 Apr 2016 05:02:26` (which is collected form log line) and for end time would be the current time of machine,

I want to calculate `end time - start time`. For that I need the Start time to be in format of current time.
I tried subtracting current time which is already a Time::Piece Object and converting `$start_time` into Time:Piece object.

But I am getting "Error parsing time at C:/Perl/lib/Time/Piece.pm line 469, line 1071883." error. Please suggest.
Also this "1071883" num in error is changing everytime I run the script. Not sure if its a kind of garbage value or what.

Editing the code with below suggested answer
I am getting below output. Seems the problem is coming as $now contains the DAY value like saturday but our $start_time doesnt. However i cant make any change in start time like adding the day value to it as we are collecting it from a log file. If the problem is due to the reason I stated, Kindly suggest how to ignore that day value from $now.

Output :

```
last line of log: 16 Apr 2016 03:41:49 -- DEBUG -- 16 Apr 2016 03:41:49 
Time is Sat Apr 16 03:43:02 2016 
difference is 21673
```

Below is what I tried:

```
#get last line of log
open my $fh ,"<","$slogfile";
my $last_line;
$last_line = $_,while (<$fh>);      
print OUTLOG "last line of log: $last_line \n";

if ($last_line=~ m/^(\d\d) (\w{3}) (\d{4}) (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d) --/) {
    $start_time = "$1 $2 $3 $4:$5:$6";
    print OUTLOG "$start_time\n";
} else {
    print OUTLOG "pattern matching didnt work\n";
}

#get current time
my $t = localtime;
#my $current_time = $t ;
print OUTLOG "Time is $current_time \n";

my $format = '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S';

my $diff = $t - Time::Piece->strptime($var, $format);

print OUTLOG "difference is  $diff \n";
```

Comment: The `line 1071883` indicates the last line read, which probably changes as your log file evolves in time.

The format you're using needs 7 parameters, but you only provide 6, i.e. `%Y` is nowhere to be found in `$start_time`.

Answer (score 1):

Your format doesn't match the format of your date. The format you're using is "'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y", which would match "Thu Apr 14 05:02:26 2016". You can get an explanation of the various pieces of your format from "man strftime" or "man strptime".

I've corrected the format definition in this example.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Time::Piece;

my $format = '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S';

my $start_time = '14 Apr 2016 05:02:26';
my $now = localtime;

my $diff = $now - Time::Piece->strptime($start_time, $format);

say "$diff seconds"; # $diff stringifies to seconds
say $diff->minutes, ' minutes';
```

The output is:

```
186402 seconds
3106.7 minutes
```

**Update:**

> Seems the problem is coming as $now contains the DAY value like
>   saturday but our $start_time doesnt. However i cant make any change in
>   start time like adding the day value to it as we are collecting it
>   from a log file. If the problem is due to the reason I stated, Kindly
>   suggest how to ignore that day value from $now.

No. That's not the problem at all. If you print out the the Time::Piece object that you parse from `$start_time` then you'll see that also has the day name included. That's just how Time::Piece objects stringify.

The actual problem is more subtle. It seems that when Time::Piece parses a date string, it assumes that it is in UTC unless the string contains an explicit time zone. From what you're saying I'm assuming that your on the east coast of the US, which would explain the ~6 hour differences that you're getting.

I'm investigating this further and will almost certainly submit a patch to Time::Piece to fix this (it might just be a documentation patch to make the behaviour clearer). But in the meantime, you need a fix. And that's pretty simple. You just need to add the time zone to your code. The relevant sections of your code will now look like this:

```
my $format = '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S%z'; # %z added here

# Append timezone here (-0600 as you're six hours behind UTC -
# adjust that if my assumption is wrong)
my $diff = $t - Time::Piece->strptime($var . '-0600', $format);
```

Or (as, quite rightly, pointed out in the comments by Borodin) you could just switch to using UTC throughout).

```
my $t = gmtime;

my $format = '%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S';

my $diff = $t - Time::Piece->strptime($var, $format);
```

Comment: `$diff` is a `Time::Seconds` object so you can `say $diff->minutes, ' minutes'`

Comment: Of course you can. No idea what I was thinking. Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: I am getting below output, while using modified format. Seems the problem is coming as $now  contains the DAY  like saturday but our $start_time doesnt. However i cant make any change in start time like adding the day value to it as we are collecting it from a log file. If the problem is due to the reason I stated, Kindly suggest how to ignore that from $now. Output I got:::::: last line of log: 16 Apr 2016 03:41:49 -- DEBUG -- 
 
16 Apr 2016 03:41:49
Time is Sat Apr 16 03:43:02 2016 
difference is  21673

Comment: It is impossible to make sense of data like that dumped in a comment. Please edit your question to add this information.

Comment: That output seems to be correct. Why do you think there is a problem?

Comment: The output should be around 2minutes, i.e. difference of 03:43 - 03:41, even if it comes in seconds it should be near to 120 seconds but the output is something in 20 thousands.

Comment: @DaveCross Hi Dave, where do you think the issue could be

Comment: See my update. And can I remind you that unless you're paying me, I get to reply whenever **I** want :-)

Comment: Or you can use `gmtime` instead of `localtime` for `$now`. Both are exported by `Time::Piece`

Comment: @DaveCross Sure, you can. I just wanted to make sure this doesn't go off your radar. Sorry if I made you uncomfortable with that. Also thanks for your turnaround. I need to implement this in different time zone including eastern time mountain time etc. However, I liked thought of switching to UTC for both times as my main motive is to get the difference in two. Thanks again.