# Find number of days in Perl

Tags: perl, time

I have two dates in the format year-month-day hour:minute:sec

For example : `2015-01-01 10:00:00` and `2015-01-10 11:00:00`. I want to calculate number of days between these two days as `10`.

I tried localtime function, but didn't work. I need a solution for this in perl. Please help.

Comment: For example, the [Time::Piece](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) with [Time::Seconds](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Seconds) could help a lot.

Comment: Are you rounding everything up? I would expect the difference for those dates to be 9 days (plus a smidge), not 10 days. Similarly, I would expect the difference between `2015-01-01` and `2015-01-02` to be 1 day, not 2 days.

Comment: Similar: [How can I calculate the number of days between two dates in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/821423/176646)

Comment: what if the times were 10 and 10?  11 and 10?  are these in some particular timezone?  if so, what would be the expected effect on the result if daylight savings started or ended between the two times?

Comment: it was like hotel check in/out times : 10 to 10 calculated as one day and 10 to 10:30 will be calculated as two days

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Time::Piece has been a standard module in Perl for awhile:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature qw(say);
use Time::Piece;

my $date1 = '2015-01-01 10:00:00';
my $date2 = '2015-01-10 11:00:00';

my $format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S';

my $diff = Time::Piece->strptime($date2, $format)
   - Time::Piece->strptime($date1, $format);

# subtraction of two Time::Piece objects produces a Time::Seconds object 
say $diff->days;
```

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Thanks, I had forgotten that. I will update.

Comment: It may not be necessary to `use Time::Seconds` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(
    Time::Piece->strptime('2015-01-01 10:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  - Time::Piece->strptime('2015-01-10 11:00:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
)->days
```

Since [v5.9.5](http://perlpunks.de/corelist/version?module=Time%3A%3APiece) [`Time::Piece`](http://p3rl.org/Time::Piece) is part of the core Perl distribution

Comment: It's a correct answer, but would benefit from some expansion as to what's actually going on.